# How to change email templates for multiple stores?

Tags: template, email, email-templates

I need help. I have one admin area with several shops. I need customize email templates for each store.
Is there any quick way to do it?

If I add css classes in email templates, then magento removes them.

I can do it making several copies of the same template with inline css styles, but it is very long and the number of letters is huge.

How to do it without making copies of email templates?

Thanks.

Comment: read this article it maybe help you out.
https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-theming/1670-customizing-magento-email-templates

Answer (score 1):

[What Vsld is saying](https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-theming/1670-customizing-magento-email-templates), install [Yireo EmailOverride](https://www.yireo.com/software/magento-extensions/email-override) (please not via MageConnect), then you are able to load the emails from your theme folder. If these folders differ for all stores, your problem is solved.

I love this extension, if it works. Never used it, though.

Comment: The email override code does work well, I have used it myself.